# Making an NSButton resize its image (Cocoa OSX)

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsbutton

I could not find a way in the documentation to tell an NSButton to resize its image to fill up the whole button.  Is there a way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest you'll get is [-setImageScaling:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSButtonCell/setImageScaling:) ... look up the constants to see how the image will be scaled within the button cell, given its bordered state and bezel type.

If you're looking to *replace* the standard button entirely with your image (ie, the button cell doesn't draw itself at all - your image serves as the entire visual representation), turn off the border (-setBordered:).

All of these options can be configured in IB as well. A tip: in IB, hover the mouse over any setting in the inspector panel - most if not all give you a hint that shows what method controls the behavior affected by the setting's control.