# Have NSButton title wider than its image

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, appkit

I have the following setup:
[image]
As you can see, the title 'Load from CMK' is being clipped. Is there a way to arrange the image so that the full title will be expressed, even if it means overlapping other elements?

It looks like using [ImageScaling](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbutton/2202284-imagescaling) might be a solution, but in what way I am not sure (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976673/making-an-nsbutton-resize-its-image-cocoa-osx)).

Comment: Use the line break property.

Answer (score 1):

Set Scaling to 'None', and if image parameters are too small/too big, manually adjust it outside of the application.
With this Scaling setting as long as the image is not too big the title fits cleanly underneath.

[image]